# Create INSERT script with incrementing ID for linked tables (SQL server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a regular task which involves exporting two tables from one database and importing the data into another database whose corresponding tables are not empty. One of the tables in question has a column which refers to the ID of the first. Let's call them Customer and Customer_Address where Customer_Address has a column Cust_ID referring to ID in the Customer table.

I need to create an import script for these which will add the Customer records to the other, non-empty DB with ID = max(id)+1 for each row while not breaking the link to the other table. The Customer_Address table likewise has its own ID column which needs to be incremented in the same manner.

I don't strictly need to have the first inserted record be one higher than the existing highest ID, but it would be best. I've managed in the past to manually check the highest ID in the target DB and add this number using search and replace and a variable in the import script but it's laborious and fails if any records are added to the target DB in the interim.

I have another method which involves selecting, copying, pasting and SQL-wrapping selected all columns but ID from the source tables using Excel and using select(max) instead of the ID but again it's rather tedious.

**Edit with data:**
Sample script to create source and destination tables (in the same/temdb database for convenience) is here: 
http://pastebin.com/C64wFtsP

Should give output as follows:

```
select * from customer
```

```
id  Last    First
1   Johnson James
2   Kelly   Karl
3   Lawlor  Liam
```

```
select * from customer2
```

```
id  Last    First
1   Adams   Ann
2   Byrne   Bressie
3   Casey   Charlene
```

```
select * from customeraddress
```

```
id  idclient street         city        county  country
1   1       65 North St.    Marcoussin  Jojoba  Flatland
2   2       42 South St.    Marcoussin  Jojoba  Flatland
3   3       12 West St.     Marcoussin  Jojoba  Flatland
4   1       17 East St.     Marcoussin  Jojoba  Flatland
5   1       75 Centre St.   Marcoussin  Jojoba  Flatland
```

```
select * from customeraddress2
```

```
id  idclient street         city        county  country
1   1       99 North St.    Marcoussin  Jojoba  Flatland
2   2       88 South St.    Marcoussin  Jojoba  Flatland
3   3       88 West St.     Marcoussin  Jojoba  Flatland
4   1       66 East St.     Marcoussin  Jojoba  Flatland
5   1       55 Centre St.   Marcoussin  Jojoba  Flatland
```

What I'm looking for is a way to script an import of the data in both source tables to the corresponding destination tables, while preserving the link between the idclient in customeraddress and the id in customer.

Comment: Anytime you use MAX(ID) + 1 you are setting yourself for failure. There are SO many things that can go wrong here. As posted your question is entirely too broad and there are not enough details.

Comment: What's the best way to make it clearer? Is it OK if I provide a small sample database (source and target) ?

Comment: http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks, Sean. Added table creation and query code

Comment: Can you create any sort of temporary / staging tables in your destination?

Comment: As long as it's removed immediately after the import, it's not a problem to do so

Comment: @KyleHale were you thinking of something along the lines of copying the data in the source DB to a temp table and changing the index?

Comment: Yeah, what you're describing is a very standard ETL process, the easiest way is to stage the data, insert your users, then join on the natural key back to your staged data to insert the correct new IDs in the customeraddress field.

Answer (score 0):

If you can stage data in your destination database, just do this:

1. Stage both tables in Destination, all fields.
2. Insert users into new Destination table.
3. Write a query like this

Note that you'll need to identify a natural key for your customers (the thing that makes them distinct entities in Customer1 that also exists in Customer2) - firstName, lastName probably isn't the best as they're highly unlikely to be distinct across your customer base, but it's what you've got in your sample data.

```
INSERT INTO customeraddress2
SELECT
  customer2.id,
    staged_customeraddress1.street,
    staged_customeraddress1.city,
    staged_customeraddress1.county,
    staged_customeraddress1.country
FROM customer2
JOIN staged_customer1
    ON staged_customer1.firstName = customer2.firstName
    AND staged_customer1.lastName = customer2.lastName
JOIN staged_customeraddress1
    ON staged_customeraddress1.idclient = staged_customer1.id
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are no unique common identifiers. It would be very easy to do if I could just match the addresses to the names based on, say, a mobile number or loyalty card number, but these fields are very often blank in the databases I'm working with.